# Not able to filter for Inactive rules in SonarQube Findbugs plugin

Tags: findbugs, sonarqube5.1

I have setup a VM with SonarQube 5.1.2 and FindBugs v3.2 plugin. When browsing through the rules, I have played around and Deactivated some of the rules to check the functionality. Now I'm not able to filter/find the Inactive rules from the Rules tab or Profiles tab.

How can I find Inactive rules from the UI?

Thanks,
Vinay.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.6 version you must go to the Rules bookmark and choose one of Quality Profiles on the left. Then switch button appears and you can choose if active or inactive rules should be listed.